# Zend Framework: add data to layout for every action of controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, web-applications, zend-layout, zend-controller-plugin

i am writing a web application and i need all the data returned/computed in all actions of one specific controller to return data to the layout (not the view).

So after each action, a controller variable needs to be passed to the layout so the layout can use it.

In detail, i want to store the calculated data in jSon in the head.

Any ideas anyone of how to do this?
I thought about a controller plugin but i have no idea of how to access the desired parameters then and i really don't want to use a singleton for all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let use, this method is executed before every action

```
public function preDispatch() {
}
```

for example

```
public function preDispatch()
{
        //calculate something
        //this is an example
        if($this->getRequest()->getActionName()=="admin")
        {
            $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('admin');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('user');
        }
}
```

Comment: Wait, so i can use the methods that i would define in the plugin in the controller as well? How did i not know that? I actually never saw anyone doing this. Thanks for pointing it out to me! Have a nice day!

Comment: Like i said. Yes. Thank you. Actually already tried it and works fine ... Didn't know i had a brother though. But the more the marier right? ;-D

Comment: @AndreschSerj haha you're so funny :)